# innerHTML and &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, html

I have a weird JavaScript behavior which I cannot explain.

Consider this code:

```
var el = document.createElement('div')
var s = String.fromCharCode(160)

el.innerHTML = s

console.log(s)            // prints space
console.log(el.innerHTML) // prints "&nbsp;"
```

Now I know that `&#160;` is non-breaking space, but technically, I just made an assignment of one variable to another, both are strings. 
How come the values are different?

Is `innerHTML` a special kind of string or something?

How does it work? What Is the mechanism which translates this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> technically, I just made an assignment of one variable to another, both are strings. How come the values are different?

Because yes, `innerHTML` is special. It's not just a simple value property, it's an *accessor* property. When you assign to it, you're calling a function under-the-covers which parses the HTML you give it and creates the necessary DOM nodes and elements. When you read its value, you're calling another function under-the-covers which recurses through the DOM tree starting from the element on which you access it and builds an HTML string representing that DOM tree.

So while you assigned the character U+00A0 to it, that got turned into a DOM text node; and when you read from it, that DOM text node was rendered as a canonical (per that browser's rules) HTML string: `&nbsp;`.

You can see that `innerHTML` isn't just a simple value property by using the DOM to manipulate the element:

```js
var target = document.getElementById("target");
target.innerHTML = "\u00A0";
console.log(target.innerHTML); // "&nbsp;"
target.appendChild(
  document.createElement("span")
);
console.log(target.innerHTML); // "&nbsp;<span></span>"
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Note that it's possible to define accessor properties in JavaScript objects as well; it's not just the DOM that can have them:

```js
var o = {
  get foo() {
    console.log("foo getter called");
    return this._foo;
  },
  set foo(value) {
    console.log("foo setter called");
    this._foo = value;
  }
};
console.log("foo: " + o.foo);
o.foo = 42;
console.log("foo: " + o.foo);
```

The fact that `innerHTML` is a property with a getter and setter is why code like this is poor practice:

```
for (var n = 0; n < something.length; ++n) {
    element.innerHTML += ", " + something[n];
}
```

That's constantly building and then destroying and rebuilding a DOM tree and making a **bunch** of hidden function calls. Instead, you'd build the string, *then* assign it.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense,
So it's not a simple value propery, it's sortof C# style property with logic behind it? 
In this case, it's weird that `el.innerHTML.__proto__` still says this is _String_

Comment: @YossiVainshtein: Yes, just like C# properties. No, it's not strange that `el.innerHTML.__proto__` is `String`. :-) You're accessing `__proto__` on the **return value** of the getter function (which is a string), not the getter function itself. (Just like `x = el.innerHTML; x.__proto__;`). Instead, you'd want to look at the result of [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(el, "innerHTML")`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.getownpropertydescriptor), but since it's a DOM property, the browser doesn't have to support that operation on it. (But if you wanted to see a JS object's accessor...)

Answer (score 4):

`innerHTML` is not a simple property, it's an *accessor* property with `getter` and `setter`. Means that under the hood functions work.  `innerHTML` serializes the given input into HTML. It parses the given value, creates elements and nodes, then appends those ones to the element.

It is defined like this

```js
const DOMElement = {
  value: null,
  set innerHTML(html) {
     console.log(`Setting html: ${html}`);
     // Translate into elements and nodes, then append to the element
     this.value = html;
  },
  get innerHTML() {
     console.log(`Getting html:`);
     // Translate into string, then return it
     return this.value;
  }
};

DOMElement.innerHTML = '<p>Hello</p>';
console.log(DOMElement.innerHTML);
```

If you want to print the given character without serializing, you can use `textContent` property.

Comment: so it is a special String, not a regular property of a regular JavaSciprt object?

Comment: Yes, it is not a regular property. Under the hood it translates the given value into HTML style - making nodes or elements

Comment: @YossiVainshtein: That depends on what you mean by "regular." It's not a *value* property, it's a property with accessors (in this case, defined by the DOM object, but you can do that with a JavaScript object as well).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder with getter and setter, not just a simple property.

Comment: @SurenSrapyan: That's what I said: A property with accessors.